# Laravel Lumen same route with different methods not working

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to create a microsservice/REST Api with Laravel's Lumen micro-framework, but my routes aren't working as expected.

The idea is to make some microsservices in REST format, and manage "base" url within the server (NGINX, Apache, etc). So, my "root" endpoint is always the root of the application (the / route).

My routes/web.php config file looks this way:

```php
/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

$router->get("/", "ApiModule@list");
$router->get("/{id}", "ApiModule@read");
$router->post("/", "ApiModule@create");
$router->put("/{id}", "ApiModule@update");
$router->delete("/{id}", "ApiModule@delete");
```

Some explanation for my routes:

| Route | Method | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| / | GET | List all courses |
| /{id} | GET | Get specified course |
| / | POST | Create a course |
| /{id} | PUT | Update course |
| /{id} | DELETE | Delete specified course |

All my routes are working as expected, EXCEPT the `POST /`, which is used to create new courses. When I call that route with POST method with Postman (for testing), the response is the same as returned by the `GET /` route. Adding some debug (like `dd` or `var_dump` or `echo`) in the `ApiModule@create` method, the response stills the same as `GET /`. So, my conclusion is the `POST /` isn't working, and the `GET /` is used instead.

I've already tried to create a middleware to add some headers that allows GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and OPTIONS methods, re-ordering routes, leaving `POST /` above `GET /` for priority, and commenting the `GET /` route. No success at all.

Commenting `GET /` route, when testing with Postman, the `POST /` returns a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know if you have in lumen, but if you have, try the command `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @GiacomoM Yes, I'm in Lumen. Running ```php artisan route:list``` outputs a table with all my routes. The list is ok, all 5 routes (GETs, POST, PUT and DELETE routes) are shown as expected.

Comment: write please the content of your controller. Why you say the POST response is the same of GET?

Comment: When I call POST or GET, it shows the result expected only for GET (returns a list of all courses). Looks like the POST is calling ```ApiModule@list``` instead ```ApiModule@create```. Here is my controller: https://pastebin.com/FD2XVXNe The GET is pointing to the ```list``` method, and POST is pointing to ```create``` method.

Comment: Even when commenting your get '/' route you are receiving a 405 response? This is weird. Did you try to add some extra dummy post route (just dd a response) to check if there isn't some config issue with POST?

Comment: @FabriceLefloch Yes, if I comment the ```GET /``` route, the ```POST /``` returns 405 response. Tried to make another route (```POST /make```), that just returns the input, and it's working fine. Looks this is a bug or something else having a POST route at application's root (the / uri).

Comment: I just tested to create a POST route on / and it's working perfectly fine. Just in case did you double check that your ApiModule@create is correctly defined (no typo). You can check by writing directly your response in the router like this `$router->post('/', function () use ($router) {
    return json_encode("My default POST route");
});` Any informations you can get on Lumen logs or your server logs (Nginx or Apache)?

Comment: @FabriceLefloch Tested your approach, writing the response directly on router, but stills returning as a GET, not a POST. In Apache access logs, I've checked there are 301 redirects from my URL without ending slash to a URL with ending slash. So, it looks like Lumen is redirecting root requests without a ending slash to a "slash ended" route, but mismatching to follow same method (POST). If I add an slash at the end directly on request, it works fine. But, there's something I can do to avoid this?

Comment: OK, so you issue is probably not related to Lumen, but rather to Apache and your .htaccess. Did you add some custom config in your .htaccess file?

Comment: @FabriceLefloch No, the .htaccess in /public folder is the original that comes with Lumen. Also tried an NGINX-based server on a virtual machine, and received same behaviour.